# I want to draw the sheet music using MusicXml in android app

Tags: android, jfugue, musicxml

I tried various ways to do this.

1. Using proxymusic-2.0.jar Library
   => Marshalling and unmarshalling done between Java object and Xml file,
   but I didn't find a way to draw it unmarshalled from Xml file on Android app(Activity, View, etc.)
2. Using JFugue-4.0.3-with-musicxml.jar Library
   => I think this library is very useful due to MusicXmlParser, MusicXmlRenderer and ParserListener class. However, The current state of Midi support on Android is depressing. They ripped out javax.sound.midi, so all libraries that depend on this are not working. (Things like JFugue for example, OMG).

I just want to show musicXml file to sheet music on android!!!
Please recommend me the reference site, or let me know the simple sample code url for resolve this issue.

thank you very much.

Comment: any luck on creating this?

Comment: OpenSheetMusicDisplay

Answer (score 1):

Try [https://www.neoScores.com](https://www.neoscores.com)... It's not perfect yet, but we are working really hard to get the job done in HTML5.
It's a custom-written musicXML renderer in javascript. There's no api available (YET) but at the #classicalhackdays in Vienna we made a small hack in cooperation with music21 that should allow people to make an http-request with the musicXML in a post-variable...
Just send your score in a (post)var called "xmlin" to https://www.neoscores.com/post... We didn't get to the point to test this thoroughly, but ... hope it works for you ...

Either way, you should be able to create an account in neoScores, and use DropBox inside this webapp to access your own sheets.
Annotations are coming within a couple of weeks...
We are testing neoScores crossplatform. For Android we test on Samsung Galaxy Notes & Tabs 10.1 with Android 4.0.4 up to 4.3. If you could give some feedback for the device(s) you are using, that would be a great help for us.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this http://musicxml-viewer.com/
I have not tested on Android browser but it works on iOS browser and from that standpoint (no support for Java or Flash) they stand at same level - so hopefully it'll do the job

regards

Comment: "NOTICE: This domain name expired on 5/4/2017 and is pending renewal or deletion."

Answer (score 0):

There's now a [Android JFugue](https://github.com/kshoji/JFugue-for-Android) port on GitHub.

Also check the commercial [SeeScore SDK for Android](http://www.seescore.co.uk/developers/) .